# What exactly happens when ` import Foo from "Bar" ` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

When you import a module without a '.' or '..'
For example : `import File from 'FileClass';`
How the ts compiler resolves `'FileClass'` exactly?

The Doc says

> - Module names may be relative or top-level. A module name is relative if the first term is "." or "..".
> - Top-level names are resolved off the conceptual module name space root.
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#11.3.1

So the `'FileClass'` must be a so called `top-level` module.
But, the doc didn't explain what is a `top-level` module.

The first question for me is that what the term `top-level` means? And what is a `conceptual module name space root`?

Continue to read the doc, and I found this

> If the import declaration specifies a top-level module name and the program contains no AmbientModuleDeclaration (section 12.2) with a string literal that specifies that exact name, the name is resolved in a host dependent manner (for example by considering the name relative to a module name space root). If a matching module cannot be found an error occurs.

This is hard to understand for me. Is there a realworld example for this ?

PS: I'm using TypeScript 1.5

Comment: You can examine compiled `.js` files and see what exactly happens.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what module system you use with your compiler. For example if you use `--module commonjs` you module syntax is converted to node.js module syntax such as `var module = require('module');` In that case if you dont use relative path `'./module'` but only module name the dependecy is resolved in `node_modules` folder. For the AMD it works similar but i dont exactly know what is the root for AMD modules.